# how do I run this Emacs M-x command "wg-update-workgroup" automatically before emacs closes?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like this to happen when I right click the launcher...icon..and select quit..and choose file exit. I would like this command to be run right before emacs exits....so when I right click the launcher icon and select quit then this command "wg-update-workgroup" is run then Emacs exits..I've tried learning about hooks but don't get how to add one....If someone can give me exact code I put into my initialization file I would be very grateful....tried binding a function to a key but get weird command p error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
          (lambda ()
            (wg-update-workgroup)))
```

### UPD

It seems that the code isn't working for you since `wg-update-workgroup` needs an argument.
You have to test this yourself, since I don't really want to get familiar with the package.

Solution 1:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
          (lambda ()
            (wg-update-all-workgroups)))
```

Solution 2:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
          (lambda ()
            (call-interactively 'wg-update-workgroup)))
```

### UPD: disregard everything from above:)

I'm pretty sure this is what you want:

```
(setq wg-query-for-save-on-emacs-exit nil)
(push (lambda()(or (ignore-errors
            (wg-update-all-workgroups-and-save)) t))
  kill-emacs-query-functions)
```

The first statement removes the extremely annoying y/n query about saving
workgroups on exit. The second statement saves everything unconditionally on exit.

Just to list my full configuration:

```
(require 'workgroups)
(workgroups-mode 1)
(setq wg-query-for-save-on-emacs-exit nil)
(wg-load "~/wg")
(push (lambda()(or (ignore-errors
            (wg-update-all-workgroups-and-save)) t))
  kill-emacs-query-functions)
```

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't hurt. Besides, I have no idea how `wg-update-workgroup` works.
Maybe it will need to be called with an argument at some point.

Comment: @user2735131 should be sure to read the doc about `kill-emacs-hook`. Dunno what `wg-update-workgroup` does exactly, but this might be pertinent (from the doc string): "Since `kill-emacs` may be invoked when the terminal is disconnected (or in other similar situations), functions placed on this hook should not expect to be able to interact with the user. To ask for confirmation, see `kill-emacs-query-functions` instead."

Comment: when i use your code @abo-abo  i get this error:

 Wrong number of arguments: #[(workgroup) "ÁÂ!\"ÃÄÅÆ\"ÄÇÈÉÊ!\"\"P!" [workgroup wg-set-base-config wg-working-config wg-msg wg-add-face :cmd "Updated: " :cur format "%s" ...] 8 ("/home/w/.emacs.d/workgroups.elc" . 65813) (list (wg-arg))], 0

...the wg-update-workgroup command is from https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el if you do a search for wg-update-workgroup at the previous link it will explain it

Comment: @abo-abo   still newish to the detailed stuff......here is the 2 functions from workgroups.el if you can still guide me....

Comment: (defun wg-update-workgroup (workgroup)
  "Set the base config of WORKGROUP to its working config in `selected-frame'."
  (interactive (list (wg-arg)))
  (wg-set-base-config workgroup (wg-working-config workgroup))
  (wg-fontified-msg
   (:cmd "Updated: ") (:cur (wg-name workgroup))))

Comment: (defun wg-update-all-workgroups ()
  "Update all workgroups' base configs.
Worgroups are updated with their working configs in the
`selected-frame'."
  (interactive)
  (mapc #'wg-update-workgroup (wg-list))
  (wg-fontified-msg (:cmd "Updated: ") (:msg "All")))

Comment: the

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
          (lambda ()
            (call-interactively 'wg-update-all-workgroups)))

didn't cause an error but it didn't work though(i changed funtion for better result)

Comment: I'll see if I can learn the package tomorrow. When I know how it works, I'll probably pinpoint the error that you get.

Comment: @abo-abo That was very kind of you to help me thanks for all your time....will try tomorrow and post back if it works

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be baffled. The issue is this: when Emacs begins exiting, workgroups.el cleans itself up earlier than 'kill-emacs-hook. What you want is this:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions 'wg-update-all-workgroups)
```

The hook variable should then look something like this:

```
(wg-update-all-workgroups wg-emacs-exit-query)
```

I recommend using 'wg-update-all-workgroups rather than 'wg-update-workgroup if, like me, you have more than one workgroup saved in a given workgroups file.

IMO workgroups.el is the best Emacs session manager. Somebody new has just taken it over. I'm excited that a new version with even more features may be forthcoming:

https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2/

Comment: @"Tom Davey" where do I put the  hook variable or do I (setf wg-update-all-workgroups (wg-update-all-workgroups wg-emacs-exit-query)) right before (add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions 'wg-update-all-workgroups)  in my init

Comment: @user2735131 The add-hook function will update the hook variable (the first argument) with the second argument. So, put this -- (add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions 'wg-update-all-workgroups) -- in your init and you should be all set. NB: In the list of functions composing the hook, make sure that 'wg-update-all-workgroups appears before 'wg-emacs-exit-query, as I show in the answer. Depending on your setup, to get the correct order you may need to (require 'workgroups) or otherwise load it before adding the new function to 'kill-emacs-query-functions.